Ubuntu installation can only be accessed via BIOS
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 from an ISO burned in a flash drive, in a laptop that previously had dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu 18.04 (I just wanted to update Ubuntu). The installation was successful; however, when I turn on my laptop, instead of showing the usual dual boot screen, it takes me directly to Windows.
I can access my new Ubuntu installation by entering the BIOS from Windows and manually selecting the third option in the list:
Boot options:

What can I do to recover my dual boot screen?
